# Complexity of all nearest neighbours problem

Tags: algorithms

Given a set $P$ of points $P=\left\{p_1,p_2,\dots p_n\right\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$

What I want to show is that **every correct algorithm** which finds for every $p_i$ the nearest neightbour, 
i.e. the point $p_j$ such that $dist(p_i,p_j)\le dist(p_i,p_k)$ for every $k\neq i$,
**takes $\Omega(n\log(n))$ steps in worst case.**

Assume I already have found the nearest neighbour for every point, is it possible to construct the Voronoi diagram of $P$ in linear time? In that case there cannot be an algorithm, which finds all nearest neighbours faster that $\Omega(n\log(n))$ because I already know, that construction of Voronoi diagram takes at least $\Omega(n\log(n))$ steps.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for your last sentence? I do not recall hearing that $O(n\log n)$ is the best possible.

Comment: @LordSoth: It is possible to construct the convex hull of P in linear time, if you know the Voronoi diagram, but construction of convex hull takes at least $\Omega(nlog(n))$ in WC, so construciton of Voronoi diagramm cannot be faster.

Comment: OK, thanks for the Q&A inside the Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), which has a known lower bound of $\Omega(n \log n)$ under the algebraic decision tree model.

The point set contains equal elements clearly iff the nearest neighbor of some point is at the same position.